# How to know which sprite has collided from the group?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I created a class and each member of this class is a member of my group of sprites. I test the collision between my player and the group with:

```py
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,surprise_sprites,False)
```

and I would like to know which sprite of my group has collided in order to use function from their class.

```
class Surprise(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,win):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, sol_sprites)
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, surprise_sprites)
        self.width = TILESIZE
        self.height = TILESIZE
        self.image = Block_surprise
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.win = win
        self.exist = True

    def update(self):
        if self.exist:
            self.collision()
        win.blit(self.image,(camera.apply_player([self.rect.x]),self.rect.y))

    def collision(self):
        blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,player_sprite,False)
        if not (blocks_hit_list == []):
            self.exist = False
            self.image = brick_img
            print("TOUCHE")

    def i_want_to_execute_a_function_here(self):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) returns the list of the sprites which collided.
A sprite list can be traversed:

```py
blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,surprise_sprites,False)
for hit_sprite in blocks_hit_list:
    # [...] whatever e.g.
    # hit_sprite.myMethod();
```

Comment: I think the second argument to `spritecollide()` should be `surprise_sprites` not `player_sprite`, but otherwise this is good advice.

Comment: @martineau Yeah, probably. But that is hard to say. In the question first is uses `surprise_sprites` and then `player_sprite`

Comment: Because `surprise_sprites` is plural, I tend to think it's the correct choice. From the snippet of code in the OP's question it's also unclear how to use the `i_want_to_execute_a_function_here()` method with each `hit_sprite` in the returned `blocks_hit_list`...

Comment: @martineau Yes, there are some things unclear. But I think that the questioner didn't know how to access the colliding sprites.

Comment: @martineau yep thats want i wanted to do